# Is it possible for jQuery slideDown() function to apply display:flex property instead of display:block?

Tags: jquery, css

I have this:

```
function searchOpen() {
    $('.account').addClass('account--open');
    $('.account-dropdown').slideDown(250);
    $('.account-dropdown').addClass('account-dropdown--open');
    $('.account-dropdown input').focus();
}

function searchClose() {
    $('.account').removeClass('account--open');
    $('.account-dropdown').slideUp(250);    
}

function searchDropdown() {
    if ($('.account-dropdown').is(":visible")) {
        searchClose();
    } else {
        searchOpen();
    }
}
```

CSS for `account-dropdown--open` is:

```
.account-dropdown--open {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Though this workaround works, the `display: flex` is removed before the sliding up finishes which results in some unwanted visuals.

Is there a way for the `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` to apply `display: flex` instead of `display: block`?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Please try the following start callback:

```
$(".item").slideDown({
  start: function () {
    $(this).css({
      display: "flex"
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly. If you're looking to add the duration option you can add it like this: start: function() {...}, duration: 200

Answer (score 7):

Here are two potential ways you can achieve what you discuss.

**Option 1**

One method to achieve this is to wrap the element within a `div` and give the wrapper `div` a class with the `display: flex` property.

e.g (assuming your HTML structure is along these lines based on your BEM CSS):

```
<nav class="nav" class="nav___item"> 
  <div class="nav__item">
    <div style="display: flex">
      <div class="nav__item__account-dropdown--open">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Option 2**

Alternatively you could overwrite the function with an anonymous callback function, like so:

```
$('.nav__item__account-dropdown--open').slideUp(500, function() { 
  $(this).css('display', 'flex');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this is a newer behaviour, but in jQuery 3.2 at least, if the element has an inline style of display:none, jQuery *removes* this property rather than add a new display property  on slideUp(), slideToggle() etc.

So, if you set your element to display:flex in the CSS, and then apply display:none either inline using a style tag on the element, or with something similar to the below immediately on page load:

```
$('.element').css('display', 'none');
```

Then when you use slideDown() etc, you'll be left with a visible element with the correct display property.

If your element should only be hidden at a certain screen size, you can run the code to hide the element within an if statement based on screen width, eg

```
if( $(window).width() < 600){
    $('.element').css('display', 'none');
}
```

This has the potential disadvantage of the element briefly being shown until the page finishes loading, but if you're going to allow the element to be shown later on I wouldn't think this would be a big deal.  You could also use something like slideUp() to initially hide the element, so it animates away nicely.

Comment: Another way to apply the initial styles is to use `style="display: none;"` inline, and use a class, e.g. `class="make-this-flex"` with css, e.g. `.make-this-flex { display: flex; }`.  This avoids the issue of the element being briefly shown during page loading.